# Powershell - assign variables sequentially

Tags: powershell

I want to assign database to users in order like desired output. But no luck. How can we assign DBs to users?

Script :

```
$dbNames = 'db01','db02','db03','db04','db05','db06','db07','db08'

$Users="user01","user02","user03","user04","user05","user06","user07","user08","user09","user10"

foreach ($user in $Users){

    $numArchive++

    $db = $dbNames[$($numArchive % 4)]

    Write-host "$user -> $db"

}
```

My output :

```
user01 -> db02
user02 -> db03
user03 -> db04
user04 -> db01
user05 -> db02
user06 -> db03
user07 -> db04
user08 -> db01
user09 -> db02
user10 -> db03
```

My desired output :

```
user01 -> db01
user02 -> db02
user03 -> db03
user04 -> db04
user05 -> db05
user06 -> db06
user07 -> db07
user08 -> db08
user09 -> db01
user10 -> db02
and so on.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a fixed value (`4`) use the `.Count` of your `$dbNames` array. Also, you're incrementing `$numArchive` **before indexing** and you need to increment after.

```
$numArchive = 0
foreach ($user in $Users) {
    $db = $dbNames[$numArchive++ % $dbNames.Count]
    Write-Host "$user -> $db"
}
```